# Column Value in search api

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I want to get the value from a Item sublist of Sales Order record.

But unable to get it. Though I can get the value of entity fields of the SO record.

Below is the snippet of the code:

```
        var filters = new Array();
                        filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter("mainline",null,"is","T");

                        var column=new Array();
                        column[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn("trandate");
                        column[1] = new nlobjSearchColumn("item");
                        column[2] = new nlobjSearchColumn("cust_col_1");

                var result = nlapiSearchRecord('salesorder', null, filters, column);

    for(var i = 0; i<result.length; i++)
            {
                var col = result[i].getAllColumns();
                var date = result[i].getFieldValue("trandate"); //I get this
                var item_id =  result[i].getLineItemValue("item", "item", i+1); // I don't get this
                var cust_col = result[i].getLineItemValue("item", "cust_col_1", i+1); //I don't get this
            }
```

I think I am defining the columns wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part

`var item_id =  result[i].getLineItemValue("item", "item", i+1); // I don't get this
var cust_col = result[i].getLineItemValue("item", "cust_col_1", i+1); //I don't get this`

is also wrong, you use this syntax if you have loaded the record but for search results you just use

```
result[i].getValue('cust_col_1")
```

Comment: shackels and Mike Robbins.
Combined answer of you solved the problem.
Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 3):

By specifying the filter `new nlobjSearchFilter("mainline",null,"is","T")`, you're basically telling the search that you don't want any line item data.  This means that you will be unable to read any column data, custom or otherwise.

The `mainline` filter parameter has basically three options, `'F'` means you want the line item details.  `'T'` means you just want the header data.  Leaving this filter out will return one row for the header information and one row for each line item on the transaction.